# providing hints for unmatched regular expressions

Tags: regex, expression, error-correction

Has anyone (come across/worked on) a tool giving hints about the unmatched regexps with provided grammer? I.e. imagine that part of the regexp was matched up to some token but the latter failed:

```
(?P<name>[a-zA-Z])-(?P<number>\d+)_blah
```

say we managed to find the name but there was a letter before "_" (e.g. "foo-123Z_blah") or "_blah" wasn't matched (e.g. "foo-123_Zblah").

It would be really great if the user could get a hint what went wrong in a long regexp and maybe introduce some corrections etc.

I remember having read that Antlr was quite good at reversing its parsing procedure in order to provide hints for the incorrect language statements according to the provided grammer definition. Is there anything lilghtweight preferebly in Python doing something of that kind?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You should check out http://www.regexbuddy.com/ for debugging your regular expressions. It is kind of like a regex IDE and has a library full or common regexes, realtime help on regex composition as well as testing/debugging tools.

Unfortunately it's not free, but it's well worth the small amount they charge. The debugging tool is pretty great, I'm confident it'll help you. It shows which components match a string, when backtracking occurs, at which symbols etc.

It's great software, highly recommended!

Comment: Thanks infl3x, I've seen this one before but what I mean is not actually having the tool but rather a library that can give me some info so that it can be shown to the user in order to give him a hint what part of the data he entered might have been incorrect. 
I.e. I've got a set of regexps and I'm trying to match user's input to figure out what type of data he has just entered. So I've already got a set of rules defined through regexps and would like to tell the user what he did wrong so that his input was not matched.